# Java Swing applications - Window 8 tablet - On Screen Key board

Tags: java, swing, keyboard

When I click on a text field in a Java Swing based application deployed in Windows 8 tablet, the on screen key board is not opening up automatically. Do I need to implement something in order to enable this?

Or, are there any settings to be done explicitly to achieve this case?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, does the input caret appear in the text field? If so you could try to do java.awt.Component.requestFocus() or java.awt.Component.requestFocusInWindow(). If both fails, suspect a problem with your JVM and/or machine.

A particular component must be enabled and focusable (and so does all the parent components) for the text field to be focused on. Although default java properties are to have new components to be both focusable and enabled, you can enforce them by performing setEnabled(true); and setFocusable(true); on your component. Focus is usually depicted by a flashing caret.

Also make sure you don't have any strange Mouse Listeners that is consuming the mouse event.

If all else fails, **ADD** a mouse listener and a focus listener on your component to test if its receiving focus and try different ways to select it (via the tab key, via mouse click, via touch input).

Java is platform-independent. Assuming your using a AWT/Swing object the underlying mechanics should be handled automatically by the JVM whether it be on windows 8 or windows 98 (if it were supported with this version of java).

Comment: Yes, input caret is flashing. Focus isn't my issue. Its about loading of On Screen Keyboard in Win 8 tablet. I tried a simple JtextField example on the Windows 8 tablet and even that is not loading the on screen keyboard. What I did is, I wrote a HelloWorld kind off application for a Jtextfield, ran the application. It opened with a single text field, with focus already on the field (flashing caret). With the touch, I manually made it loose its focus, and again tapped on the text field. Ideally, since its a text field, the On screen key board should pop up. But this is not happening.

Comment: @ViswanathT If possible, try your application on another machine (with windows 8 and a touch screen too). If even simple applications like the JTextField example doesn't work. Its probably the JVM messing up... Needa figure out if its just your machine or every win 8 with touchscreen. Make sure java is updated to the lastest version and try a clean reinstall (preventive measure against bad installation).